# JAX WS Producing different endpoint with duplicated code

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws

I am hoping that somebody can  shed some light on some strange behaviour that we have noticed when creating a second version of a web service with a very heavy-handed approach of copying the entire first code base and pasting it within a v2 package and renaming the web service interface with a V2 ending.

The V1 version of the code is:

```java
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://service.uk.company.com/")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface ServiceSearch
```

The V2 Version of the code is:

```java
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://service.uk.company.com/")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface ServiceSearchV2
```

Everything actually works fine however what we don't understand is why the first service exposes a WSDL endpoint with our usual expected behaviour:

```py
http://localhost:8080/MyService/ServiceSearch?wsdl
```

This contains the entire service definition as you would expect. However the v2 service appears to define a wrapper wsdl which points to the actual service definition, so even though we go to this:

```py
http://localhost:8080/MyService/ServiceSearchV2?wsdl
```

this actually contains an entry which points to the actual service location:

```xml
<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8080/MyService/ServiceSearchV2?wsdl=ServiceSearchV2.wsdl" namespace="http://service.uk.company.com/">
</wsdl:import>
```

This works fine we can use the endpoint:

```py
http://localhost:8080/MyService/ServiceSearchV2?wsdl=ServiceSearchV2.wsdl
```

However I am interested in why this service is being exposed differently and there is nothing in the code to indicate that there should be any difference in the way the service is exposed.

I haven't seen this second type of endpoint before - an actual search parameter after the ?wsdl part of the endpoint and this is more a  matter of being interested in what is going on than it actually causing any problems for us

Comment: when you start the service are there any log messages referencing the generated wsdl file?

Comment: nothing differentiating them however I have found https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac19323_.htm which indicates that this is legitimate behaviour. These services are running on JBOSS which may be another clue

Comment: Becasue of the namespace being same, it might be generating the wsdl this way, can you give the name attribute in @WebService annotation or change the namespace and try.